# Matcher not matching patterns properly

Tags: java, regex

I'm making a program that validates license plates for 31 States, each have different format and go from certain values also they should not include the letters I,O or Q in any of the license plates, here are the formats:

```
AGUASCALIENTES --from AAA-0001 to AFZ- 9999 

BAJA CALIFORNIA-- from AGA-0001 to CYZ-9999 

BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR-- from  CZA-0001 to DEZ-9999 

CAMPECHE -- from DFA-0001 to DKZ-9999 

CHIAPAS --  from DLA-0001 to DSZ-9999 

CHIHUAHUA -- from   DTA-0001 to ETZ-9999 

COAHUILA -- from EUA-0001 to FPZ-9999 

COLIMA --   from FRA-0001 to FWZ-9999 

DURANGO -- from FXA-0001 to GFZ-9999 

STATE OF MEXICO -- from LGA-0001 to PEZ-9999 

GUANAJUATO -- from  GGA-0001 to GYZ-9999 

GUERRERO -- from GZA-0001 to HFZ-9999 

HIDALGO --  from HGA-0001 to HRZ-9999 

JALISCO -- from HSA-0001 to LFZ-9999 

MICHOACÁN -- from PFA-0001  to  PUZ-9999 

MORELOS --  from PVA-0001   to  RDZ-9999 

NAYARIT -- from REA-0001    to  RJZ-9999 

NUEVO LEÓN -- from  RKA-0001    to  TGZ-999 

OAXACA --   from THA-0001   to  TMZ-9999 

PUEBLA--    from TNA-0001   to  UJZ-9999 

QUERÉTARO-- from    UKA-0001    to  UPZ-9999 

QUINTANA ROO-- from URA-0001    to  UVZ-9999 

SAN LUIS POTOSÍ-- from  UWA-0001    to  VEZ-9999 

SINALOA-- from  VFA-0001    to  VSZ-9999 

SONORA-- from   VTA-0001    to  WKZ-9999 

TABASCO-- from  WLA-0001    to  WWZ-9999 

TAMAULIPAS-- from WXA-0001  to  XSZ-9999 

TLAXCALA-- from XTA-0001    to  XXZ-9999 

VERACRUZ-- from XYA-0001    to  YVZ-9999 

YUCATÁN-- from  YWA-0001    to  ZCZ-9999 

ZACATECAS-- fromZDA-0001    to  ZHZ-9999
```

So acording to the format a license plate for Campeche would go like this :
DGB-5643

I made these patterns

```
   Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a][a-z&&[^ioqghjklmnprstuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(field_val.getText()); // aguascalientes

    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[a|b|c][a-z&&[^ioqhjklmnprstuvwx]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(field_val.getText()); // bajac

    Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("[c|d][a-z&&[^ioqfghjklmnprstuvwxy]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(field_val.getText()); // bajasur

    Pattern p4 = Pattern.compile("[d][a-z&&[^ioqabcdelmnprstuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m4 = p4.matcher(field_val.getText()); // campeche

    Pattern p5 = Pattern.compile("[d][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefghjktuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m5 = p5.matcher(field_val.getText()); // chiapas

    Pattern p6 = Pattern.compile("[d|e][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefghjklmnprsuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m6 = p6.matcher(field_val.getText()); // chihuahua

    Pattern p7 = Pattern.compile("[e|f][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefghjklmnvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m7 = p7.matcher(field_val.getText()); // coahuila

    Pattern p8 = Pattern.compile("[f][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefghjklmnpxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m8 = p8.matcher(field_val.getText()); // colima

    Pattern p9 = Pattern.compile("[f|g][a-z&&[^ioqghjklmnprstuvw]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m9 = p9.matcher(field_val.getText()); // durango

    Pattern p10 = Pattern.compile("[l|m|n|p][a-z&&[^ioqf]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m10 = p10.matcher(field_val.getText()); // edomex

    Pattern p11 = Pattern.compile("[g][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m11 = p11.matcher(field_val.getText()); // guanajuato

    Pattern p12 = Pattern.compile("[g|h][a-z&&[^ioqghjklmnprstuvwxy]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m12 = p12.matcher(field_val.getText()); // guerrero

    Pattern p13 = Pattern.compile("[h][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefstuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m13 = p13.matcher(field_val.getText()); // hidalgo

    Pattern p14 = Pattern.compile("[h|j|k|l][a-z&&[^ioqabcdetuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m14 = p14.matcher(field_val.getText()); // jalisco

    Pattern p15 = Pattern.compile("[p][a-z&&[^ioqabcdevwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m15 = p15.matcher(field_val.getText()); // michoacan

    Pattern p16 = Pattern.compile("[p|r][a-z&&[^ioqefghjklmnprstu]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m16 = p16.matcher(field_val.getText()); // morelos

    Pattern p17 = Pattern.compile("[r][a-z&&[^ioqabcdklmnprstuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m17 = p17.matcher(field_val.getText()); // nayarit

    Pattern p18 = Pattern.compile("[r|s|t][a-z&&[^ioqhj]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m18 = p18.matcher(field_val.getText()); // nuevoleon

    Pattern p19 = Pattern.compile("[t][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefgnprstuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m19 = p19.matcher(field_val.getText()); // oaxaca

    Pattern p20 = Pattern.compile("[t|u][a-z&&[^ioqklm]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m20 = p20.matcher(field_val.getText()); // puebla

    Pattern p21 = Pattern.compile("[u][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefghjrstuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m21 = p21.matcher(field_val.getText()); // queretaro

    Pattern p22 = Pattern.compile("[u][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefghjklmnpwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m22 = p22.matcher(field_val.getText()); // quintanaroo

    Pattern p23 = Pattern.compile("[u|v][a-z&&[^ioqfghjklmnprstuv]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m23 = p23.matcher(field_val.getText()); // sanluispotosi

    Pattern p24 = Pattern.compile("[v][a-z&&[^ioqabcdetuvwxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m24 = p24.matcher(field_val.getText()); // sinaloa

    Pattern p25 = Pattern.compile("[v|w][a-z&&[^ioqlmnprs]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m25 = p25.matcher(field_val.getText()); // sonora

    Pattern p26 = Pattern.compile("[w][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefghjkxyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m26 = p26.matcher(field_val.getText()); // tabasco

    Pattern p27 = Pattern.compile("[w|x][a-z&&[^ioqtuvw]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m27 = p27.matcher(field_val.getText()); // tamaulipas

    Pattern p28 = Pattern.compile("[x][a-z&&[^ioqabcdefghjklmnprsyz]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m28 = p28.matcher(field_val.getText()); // tlaxcala

    Pattern p29 = Pattern.compile("[x][a-z&&[^ioqwx]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m29 = p29.matcher(field_val.getText()); // veracruz

    Pattern p30 = Pattern.compile("[y|z][a-z&&[^ioqdefghjklmnprstuv]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m30 = p30.matcher(field_val.getText()); // yucatan

    Pattern p31 = Pattern.compile("[z][a-z&&[^ioqabcjklmnprstuvwxy]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher m31 = p31.matcher(field_val.getText()); // zacatecas
```

I'm sending the result to a `textfield` called `res`

here are the matchers

```
 if (m1.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Aguascalientes");
    } else if (m2.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Baja");
    } else if (m3.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Baja Sur");
    } else if (m4.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Campeche");
    } else if (m5.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Chiapas");
    } else if (m6.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Chihuahua");
    } else if (m7.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Coahuila");
    } else if (m8.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Colima");
    } else if (m9.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Durango");
    } else if (m10.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Edomex");
    } else if (m11.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Guanajuato");
    } else if (m12.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Guerrero");
    } else if (m13.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Hidalgo");
    } else if (m14.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Jalisco");
    } else if (m15.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Michoacan");
    } else if (m16.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Morelos");
    } else if (m17.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Nayarit");
    } else if (m18.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Nuevo Leon");
    } else if (m19.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Oaxaca");
    } else if (m20.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Puebla");
    } else if (m21.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Queretaro");
    } else if (m22.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Quintana Roo");
    } else if (m23.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  San Luis Potosi");
    } else if (m24.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Sinaloa");
    } else if (m25.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Sonora");
    } else if (m26.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Tabasco");
    } else if (m27.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Tamaulipas");
    } else if (m28.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Tlaxcala");
    } else if (m29.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Veracruz");
    } else if (m30.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Yucatan");
    } else if (m31.find()) {

        res.setText(" Your State is  Zacatecas");
    }
```

In cases where the first Letter Repeats in two or three states i don't get the correct match for the state i want

For example i input ABH-6262 and i get `Your State is Baja California` as a result and i'm expecting to get Aguascalientes

Comment: Do you know how to use arrays?  When you're repeating essentially the same code 31 times, that's a strong hint that you should be using arrays or lists and looping on them.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're converting all your input strings to lower case before using these pattern matchers.  (It's confusing that you've left this out of the question, since you're talking about license plate numbers in upper case but matching only lower-case letters.)

I don't see why ABH-6262 would give you the wrong result.  However, there are definitely combinations that will produce the wrong result.  For example, you say Edomex should be from LGA-0001 to PEZ-9999.  However, your pattern

```
Pattern p10 = Pattern.compile("[l|m|n|p][a-z&&[^ioqf]][a-z][-]\\d\\d\\d\\d");
```

will accept any combination whose first letter is L, M, N, or P, which is fine, but will also accept any combination whose second letter is not F (or I, O, Q).  This means that it will accept LAA, which should belong to Jalisco; and it will not accept MFA, which should be part of Edomex.

The problem is that you want to compare three-letter "words" in alphabetical order, and regular expressions are the wrong tool for that job.  You *could* do it, with a pattern like

```
(l[g-z&&[^ioq]]|[mn][a-z&&[^ioq]]|p[a-e])[a-z&&[^ioq]]-\d\d\d\d
```

The part in parentheses, using `|` characters, means that it can match one of the alternatives.  In this case, it matches the first two letters of the license plate if one of the following is true (and if no letter is I, O, or Q):

- The first letter is L, and the second letter is G to Z;
- The first letter is M or N, and the second letter is anything;
- The first letter is P, and the second letter is A to E.

You'd have to rewrite many of your matchers to do something like this.  But this makes things much more complicated than they should be.  The fact is, you should be using string comparisons, not pattern matchers, to accomplish what you're trying to do.

You can do this with just one pattern:

```
Pattern licensePlatePattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z&&[^ioq]]{3})-\\d{4}");
```

A few things to note: The first part matches any three letters that are not I, O, or Q; but that part of the pattern is in parentheses, which creates a *group* so that we can look at the three letters later.  Note that this also uses `{3}` to mean exactly three of the thing before it (similarly `{4}`).  Also note that I used `-` by itself to match the dash, not `[-]`; you don't need to use `[]` when matching just one specific character.

Now:

```
Matcher matcher = licensePlatePattern.matcher(field_val.getText());
if (matcher.find()) {
    String letters = matcher.group(1);
        // This gets the part of the input that matches the first parenthesized
        // part of the pattern (in this case, the only parenthesized part)
    if (letters.compareTo("aaa") >= 0 && letters.compareTo("afz") <= 0) then {
        res.setText(" Your State is  Aguascalientes");
    } else if (letters.compareTo("aga") >= 0 && letters.compareTo("cyz") <= 0) then {
        res.setText(" Your State is  Baja");
    } else if (letters.compareTo("cza") >= 0 && letters.compareTo("dez") <= 0) then {
        res.setText(" Your State is  Baja Sur");
```

and so on.  This is a lot easier to understand than having 31 complex patterns.  Even better would be to put the information for the states in an array, like

```
public class StateInfo {
    private String name;
    private String lowestThreeLetters;
    private String highestThreeLetters;
    // constructor, getters -- I'll let you figure out how to write these
}

// in some other class:
public static final StateInfo[] stateInfo = new StateInfo[] {
    new StateInfo("Aguascalientes", "aaa", "afz"),
    new StateInfo("Baja", "aga", "cyz"),
    new StateInfo("Baja Sur", "cza", "dez"),
    ... };
```

and instead of 31 `if` statements, you can loop through the array:

```
    String letters = matcher.group(1);
    for (StateInfo s : stateInfo) {
        if (letters.compareTo(s.getLowestThreeLetters()) >= 0 &&
            letters.compareTo(s.getHighestThreeLetters()) <= 0) { 
            res.setText(" Your State is  " + s.getName());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @ajb 
i'm using a font that outputs only Uppercase Letters so there is no need to convert them

Comment: i used your the pattern you have me this one to be clear `Pattern licensePlatePattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z&&[^ioq]]{3})-\\d{4}");` 
and the matchers but i keep getting wrong results for the same states @ajb

Comment: I understand, but next time please clarify that the input is lower-case letters only.  The regex doesn't know or care about your font.  So if you make it look like you have upper-case letters in the input, you will confuse us.

Comment: Regarding your problem that you "keep getting wrong results": you are not giving me nearly enough details to help answer this.

Comment: it was my error i had an `if` statement not in the correct place 
with your help it works perfectly fine thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in case you want both uppercase and lower case check

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a|A][a-f[A-F]][a-z[A-Z]&&[^ioqIOQ]][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(field_val); // aguascalientes

Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[a-c[A-C]][g-y[G-Y]&&[^ioqIOQ]][a-z[A-Z]&&[^ioqIOQ]][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]");
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(field_val); // bajac
```

Answer (score -1):

It is working for me. However, not checked in details. But your patterns can be improved upon a bit. Try this as the pattern:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a|A][a-f][a-z&&[^ioq]][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(field_val); // aguascalientes

Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[a-c][g-y&&^[ioq]][a-z&&[^ioq]][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]");
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(field_val);
```

-jahanvi.bansal@gmail.com

Comment: This is wrong.  Changing the last part of the pattern to `[1-9]` means you can't use numbers which end in 0, which is wrong.  The second pattern also disallows letter combinations that should be allowed, like anything beginning with BA, BB, CA, CB, etc.